# dot (symbol) color on d3.js multiline chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, anonymous-function, multiline

I am trying to replicate [this](http://bl.ocks.org/mgold/6a32cec6380b6ce75c1e) example of a multiline chart with dots. My data is basically the same, where I have an object with `name` and `values` in the first level, and then a couple of values in the second level inside `values`. For the most part, my code works, but for some reason, the `j` index in the anonymous function for the fill returns an array of repeated `circle` instead of returning the parent of the current element. I believe this may have something to do with the way I created the svg and selected the elements, but I can't figure it out. Below is an excerpt of my code that shows how I created the svg, the line path and the circles.

```
var svgb = d3.select("body")
       .append("svg")
       .attr("id","svg-b")
       .attr("width", width)
       .attr("height", height)

var gameb = svgb.selectAll(".gameb")
                .data(games)
                .enter()
                .append("g")
                .attr("class", "gameb");

gameb.append("path")
     .attr("class", "line")
     .attr("d", function(d) {return line_count(d.values); })
     .style("stroke", function(d) { return color(d.name); })
     .style("fill", "none");

gameb.selectAll("circle")
     .data(function(d) {return d.values;})
     .enter()
     .append("circle")
     .attr("cx", function(d) {return x(d.date);})
     .attr("cy", function(d) {return y_count(d.count);})
     .attr("r", 3)
     .style("fill", function(d,i,j) {console.log(j)
                                return color(games[j].name);});
```

Comment: Can you put your whole code on codepen.io or something like that so that we have all parts of the puzzle to help you with the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`j` (or more accurately, the third parameter) will always be the nodes in the selection (the array of circles here), not the parent. If you want the parent datum you can use:

```
 .attr("fill", function() { 
   let parent = this.parentNode;
   let datum = d3.select(parent).datum();
   return color(datum.name);
  })
```

*Note that using ()=> instead of function() will change the `this` context and the above will not work.*

However, rather than coloring each circle independently, you could use a or the parent `g` to color the circles too:

```
gameb.append("g")
     .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.name); })
     .selectAll("circle")
     .data(function(d) {return d.values;})
     .enter()
     .append("circle")
     .attr("cx", function(d) {return x(d.date);})
     .attr("cy", function(d) {return y_count(d.count);})
     .attr("r", 3);
```

Here we add an intermediate `g` (though we could use the original parent with a few additional modifications), apply a fill color to it, and then the parent `g` will color the children circles for us. The datum is passed on to this new `g` behind the scenes.